# Use limit theorems to prove $\sqrt{x}\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ is continuous on $[0, 1]$

Tags: calculus, continuity

Use limit theorems to prove continuous on $[0,1]$

$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
\sqrt{x}\sin(\frac{1}{x}),  & \text{if $x \neq 0$} \\
0, & \text{if $x=0$}
\end{cases}$

The only problem point is $0$ clearly $\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ is discontinuous at $0$. when $x=0, f(x)=0$

I'm a little confused my notes showed a similar problem but that problem was factorable and plugged in the maximum value and got the same value in the interval if $f(x)=0$.

Answer (score 2):

I am not really sure what you mean by "factorabale", but I guess your example went something like

$$
|\sin (1/x)|\leq 1 \quad \text{for all } x\neq 0
$$

Then for $x\neq 0$ $|\sqrt x\sin (1/x)|\leq \sqrt x$ and as $x\to 0$ we have $\sqrt x\to 0$. Then by the squeeze theorem you get  $\sqrt x\sin (1/x)\to 0$

Answer (score 2):

Let $\epsilon >0$ be given, and $0<x \le 1$;

$|√x\sin (1/x)|\le √x$ ;

Choose $ \delta = \epsilon^2$.

Then

$0<x<\delta $ implies

$|√x\sin(1/x)| \le √x < √\delta =\epsilon$, i.e.

$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+}f(x)=f(0)$.